# SQL Query explanation with IF and INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql

Could someone please explain this SQL to me, I'm trying to edit code but I don't understand this.
This is the whole sql:

```
SELECT SQL_CACHE COUNT(c.conversation_id) AS num_messages
                FROM table1 AS c
                INNER JOIN (
                    SELECT message_id,conversation_id FROM table2
                    WHERE recipient_id=:userid  ORDER BY created DESC
                ) AS m ON(m.conversation_id=c.conversation_id)
                WHERE (c.initiator_id=:userid OR c.interlocutor_id=:userid)
                AND (c.bm_read & IF(c.initiator_id=:userid, :bminit, :bminter)) = 0
                AND (c.bm_deleted & IF(c.initiator_id=:userid, :bminit, :bminter)) = 0
                GROUP BY c.conversation_id
```

I don't understand this part:

```
INNER JOIN  (
             SELECT message_id,conversation_id FROM table2
              WHERE recipient_id=:userid  ORDER BY created DESC
            ) AS m ON(m.conversation_id=c.conversation_id)
            WHERE (c.initiator_id=:userid OR c.interlocutor_id=:userid)
            AND (c.bm_read & IF(c.initiator_id=:userid, :bminit, :bminter)) = 0
            AND (c.bm_deleted & IF(c.initiator_id=:userid, :bminit, :bminter)) = 0
```

Comment: Neither do I. It's a mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you don't understand `INNER JOIN`, [here's a good explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-join#answer-16598900). It's basically an intersection, produced by doing a `CROSS JOIN` (i.e. [Cartesian Product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) if you think of the tables as sets) and then filtering based on a condition specified in an `ON` clause.

The queries are using aliases: `c` and `m` respectively to make the overall query shorter. So, `c` is the result of:

```
SELECT SQL_CACHE COUNT(c.conversation_id) AS num_messages
FROM table1
```

and `m` is the result of:

```
SELECT message_id,conversation_id FROM table2
WHERE recipient_id=:userid  ORDER BY created DESC
```

and the `ON` clause is filtering the results of the `CROSS JOIN` of the two queries based on  whether the `conversation_id` column's value from query `c` is equal to the `conversation_id` column's value from query `m`.

The `WHERE`, `AND` and `GROUP BY` clauses after the `INNER JOIN` are simply part of the `SELECT` that are filtering the results *after* the `INNER JOIN` occurs.

The `IF` is pretty simple too:

```
IF(expr1,expr2,expr3)
```

If *expr1* is TRUE (expr1 <> 0 and expr1 <> NULL) then IF() returns *expr2*; otherwise it returns *expr3*.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this would do the same thing...

```
SELECT COUNT(c.conversation_id) num_messages
  FROM conv c
  JOIN TBL_MSG m
    ON m.conversation_id = c.conversation_id
 WHERE m.recipient_id = :userid
   AND :userid IN (c.initiator_id,c.interlocutor_id)
   AND c.bm_read    & IF(c.initiator_id=:userid, :bminit, :bminter)) = 0 -- I don't understand 
   AND c.bm_deleted & IF(c.initiator_id=:userid, :bminit, :bminter)) = 0 -- this bit.
 GROUP 
    BY c.conversation_id
```

...although you won't know which conversation_id attained which count!?!

Answer (score 0):

It is doing a subquery (after the keywords `INNER JOIN`), its result is like "a table" but it is created "on the fly", and its alias is "m".

Once you know how this subquery works, you are doing an inner join of your table "c" with the new table "m" joining by keys `m.conversation_id` and `c.conversation_id`. So you are joining conversations from different sources.

The where part is just a filter applied to the output, it depends on the content of the fields.

If you have any other question, just leave a comment ;-)